# R: Same values for confidence and prediction intervals using predict()

Tags: r, statistics, prediction

When I try to make prediction and confidence intervals, around a a linear regression model, with two continuous variables and two categorical variables (that may act as dummy variables), results for the two intervals are exactly the same. I'm using the predict() function.

I've already tried with other datasets, that have continuous and discrete variables, but not categorical or dichotomous variables, and intervals are different. I tried removing some variables from the regression model, and the intervals are still the same. On the other hand, I've already compared my data.frame with ones that are exemplified on the R documentation, and I think the problem isn't there.

```
#linear regression model: modeloReducido
summary(modeloReducido)

> Call: lm(formula = V ~ T * W + P * G, data = Datos)
> 
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -7.5579 -1.6222  0.3286  1.6175 10.4773 


 Coefficients:

       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)     
(Intercept)   0.937674   3.710133   0.253 0.800922
 T           -12.864441   2.955519  -4.353 2.91e-05 *** 
 W             0.013926   0.001432   9.722  < 2e-16 *** 
 P            12.142109   1.431102   8.484 8.14e-14 ***
 GBaja        15.953421   4.513963   3.534 0.000588 ***
 GMedia        0.597568   4.546935   0.131 0.895669
 T:W           0.014283   0.001994   7.162 7.82e-11 ***
 P:GBaja      -3.249681   2.194803  -1.481 0.141418
 P:GMedia     -5.093860   2.147673  -2.372 0.019348 *


> --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
> Residual standard error: 3.237 on 116 degrees of freedom Multiple
> R-squared:  0.9354,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.931  F-statistic:   210 on
> 8 and 116 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

#Prediction Interval
newdata1.2 <- data.frame(T=1,W=1040,P=10000,G="Media")
#EP


 opt1.PI <- predict.lm(modeloReducido, newdata1.2,
     interval="prediction", level=.95)

#Confidence interval
newdata1.1 <- data.frame(T=1,W=1040,P=10000,G="Media")
#EP

opt1.CI <- predict(modeloReducido, newdata1.1, 
    interval="confidence", level=.95)
opt1.CI
#fit      lwr      upr 
#1 70500.51 38260.24 102740.8

opt1.PI
#   fit      lwr      upr
#  1 70500.51 38260.24 102740.8
```

opt1.PI and opt1.CI should be different.

The Excel file that I was given out is in the following link: 
https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/830581/Datos%20Tarea%204.xlsx

Comment: Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: I'm also puzzled and would need to see data taht results in this set of results.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The main issue is you don't give your data/model. We can't run your code. It's not reproducible as is.

Comment: Ready! I've uploaded an Excel file.

Comment: Update: I've tried to eliminate P from the modeloReducido model and prediction values changed from the values of the confidence interval. Perhaps it is a problem in P?